# jQuery UI Autocomplete custom display, how to focus sub children instead of first level children?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use a custom template for [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), where the selectable children aren't just 1st level `<li>` child elements, they nested **5 elements deeper**.

How do I make only **certain elements**, `.search-result-single-item.ui-menu-item` focusable/selectable via the arrow keys and mouse interactions?

No matter what I try, it seems to only focus/select **1st level** children within `ul.ui-autocomplete`

Here is a sample **template** of what my **inner autocomplete results** look like:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0">
  <div class="search-mini-container">

    <div class="connecting-triangle">
      <div class="connecting-triangle-border"></div>
    </div>


    <table class="search-category">
      <tr>


        <td class="search-category-icon-container">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-star text-custom-success"></i>
        </td>

        <td class="search-category-content">

          <div class="title-view-all-container">
            <div class="search-category-title text-custom-success">
              Search Category Name
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="search-result-items">
            <div class="search-result-single-item ui-menu-item">
              Search Result #1
            </div>
            <div class="search-result-single-item ui-menu-item">
              Search Result #2
            </div>
          </div>

        </td>


      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  Where are your input fields for the Autocomplete?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle using your code with some of the demo code from the jquery ui site.  What are you trying to achieve?  https://jsfiddle.net/ochpvoxL/1/

Comment: If you post your javascript I will provide the solution and explain every part of it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to autocomplete from different categories. Here's a simple example, following the [*category* example of JQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories):

```js
  $(function() {
    $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
      _create: function() {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
      },
      _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var that = this,
          currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
          var li;
          if (item.category != currentCategory) {
            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
            currentCategory = item.category;
          }
          li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
          if (item.category) {
            li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    var data = [{
      label: "Groovy",
      category: "C-like"
    }, {
      label: "Java",
      category: "C-like"
    }, {
      label: "Perl",
      category: "C-like"
    }, {
      label: "Clojure",
      category: "Lisp"
    }, {
      label: "Scheme",
      category: "Lisp"
    }, {
      label: "Lisp",
      category: "Lisp"
    }, {
      label: "ActionScript",
      category: "Scripting"
    }, {
      label: "AppleScript",
      category: "Scripting"
    }, {
      label: "JavaScript",
      category: "Scripting"
    }, ];

    $("#search").catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: data
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

<label for="search">Search:</label>
<input id="search">
```